# Discovering interactions and transformations

Tags: r, interaction, regression-strategies

I am teaching myself regression using Regression Modeling Strategies by Harell and the author goes at quite the length to showcase the importance of modeling interactions and transformations of the initial variables. I can't help but wonder how to approach this in a more structured/automated way when dealing with a lot of potential variables.

Can we use recursive partitioning, for example, to somehow to do the work for us and then use the output as variables, shrink the estimates with LASSO to deal with colinearity and do a final step where we use some sort of filtering for feature importance.

In my mind this will leave us with a well specified model which can be manually inspected and improved if need be, but is this reasonable? Are there other ways to approach this? Are there some resources that deal with problems like this?